# Memory leak in DDXML parser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xml-parsing, nsautoreleasepool

I load data from Internet, and parse it using DDXML parser in another thread. Here is code (callback connectionDidFinishLoading: is coming in background thread, I scheduled URLConnection at background thread):

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"connection did finish load");
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    DDXMLDocument *xdoc = [[DDXMLDocument alloc] initWithData: receivedXmlData options:0 error: NULL];
    NSLog(@"document retainCount1 = %d", [xdoc retainCount]);
    NSArray *nodes = [xdoc selectNodes: @"./items/item"];
    NSLog(@"document retainCount2 = %d", [xdoc retainCount]);
    for (DDXMLElement *tabXmlItem in nodes)
    {
        // here is the parsing
    }
    NSLog(@"document retainCount3 = %d", [xdoc retainCount]);
    [xdoc release];
    [receivedXmlData setLength:0];
    [pool drain];
    [pool release];
}
```

I see in memory allocator: DDXMLDocuments, DDXMLNodes, DDXMLElements still living after the end of parsing. So, there's big amount of CFString and CFData in the memory. Why these objects aren't cleared? Maybe, I use autorelease pool wrongly or DDXML parser is with surprise?

Comment: Right after you release xdoc, try releasing 'nodes' and see if you get a crash. If not then probably DDXML is returning a non-autoreleased array (an error for sure given the name of the method returning it). If that's true, then it may be that every item IN the array was also not autoreleased.

Comment: It looks like that it was a problem in autoreleasing. Interestingly, when I move Internet connection from background to foreground thread and left only parsing in background, then autorelease pool works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`retainCount` is useless.  Don't call it.   http://whentouseretaincount.com/

No need to both `drain` and `release` the pool;  just `drain` it.

Better yet, use `@autoreleasepool {...}` around the pool's scope.

Since you are using the Allocations instrument, turn on "track reference counts".   Then you can look at the history of retains/releases on the objects that are sticking around and see why they are still around.

Comment: Thanks for answer :) I solved the problem, but I haven't understood yet how. There is a big field for research.